# How can I show/hide hidden files on Finder on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mavericks

The following script doesn't work on Mavericks:

```
# check if hidden files are visible and store result in a variable
isVisible=”$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)”

# toggle visibility based on variables value
if [ "$isVisible" = FALSE ]
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true
else
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean false
fi

# force changes by restarting Finder
killall Finder
```

**UPDATED:**

But the following script works:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true
killall Finder
```

Comment: FWIW I've found that in most cases, it's enough to only show hidden files in *Open…* dialogs by pressing `Cmd-Shift-Period`. That might be a sufficient workaround until you get an answer to this question.

Comment: It's not enough for me.

Comment: If you found the solution, please put it as an answer, not into the question. Thanks!

Comment: It's not the solution.

Comment: Why not? You said the script works, so… (although I fail to see the difference between the actual commands)

Comment: It shows hidden files and doesn't hide them.

Comment: You probably just need to compare the actual output of `defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles` with what your script looks for in the `if` condition and change it accordingly.

Comment: Daniel, how can I check the actual output? Is syntax of the condition on "if" section correct on Mavericks?

Comment: You can see the output by running the command. Syntax is correct, but it the output now shows e.g. `1` instead of `TRUE`, the condition will never be true.

Comment: `”$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)”` returns `-bash: ”FALSE”: command not found` for me.

Comment: Run it without the outer quotes and the `$()`

Comment: But `= 0` and `= 1` returns FALSE too. All variants don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Script version works fine:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set cur_state to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if cur_state = "TRUE" then
        do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE"
    else
        do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE"
    end if

    do shell script "killall Finder"

    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

Without much technical knowledge one can get the hidden files quickly and easily.
This is possible with the application that keeps running all the time and sleeps safely at night. Visit http://www.showhiddenfilesmac.com/ to get this application.

Comment: I doubt linking to an application which costs $19 will be useful when the discussion has focused on scripting methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Mac OS X app *"Show Time"* to quickly hide and show hidden files from the menubar.

It is open source and available on GitHub.

Check out the source [here](https://github.com/JamesMarino/ShowTime) and the release [here](https://github.com/JamesMarino/ShowTime/releases).